# How to select matching rows from two data frames in r

Tags: r

```
> df1
     n1 mt1
1  Mike  48
2  John  64
3 Steve  32
4   Dan  87

> df2
       n1 mt1
1   Peter  32
2   Chris  23
3 Brendan  44
4  Joseph  52
```

I would like to pick row 1 from df1 and df2. Row 2 from df1 and df2. Row 3 from df1 and df2. Row 4 from df1 and df2. I can do it with below code but wonder if there is a easier way to do it when there is hundreds of rows? I always seek the matching rows from both df's and would like them paired.

```
> m1 <- rbind(df1[1,], df2[1,])
> m2 <- rbind(df1[2,], df2[2,])
> m3 <- rbind(df1[3,], df2[3,])
> m4 <- rbind(df1[4,], df2[4,])

> m1
     n1 mt1
1  Mike  48
2 Peter  32

> m2
      n1 mt1
2   John  64
21 Chris  23

> m3
        n1 mt1
3    Steve  32
31 Brendan  44

> m4
       n1 mt1
4     Dan  87
41 Joseph  52
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Map` from base R and create a sequence of row index for `df1` and `df2` subset and `rbind` them. However, make sure you do have equal number of rows for `df1` as well as `df2` otherwise you might get some unexpected result.

```
Map(function(x, y) rbind(df1[x, ], df2[x, ]), 1:nrow(df1), 1:nrow(df2))

#[[1]]
#      n1 mt1
#1   Mike  48
#11 Peter  32

#[[2]]
#      n1 mt1
#2   John  64
#21 Chris  23

#[[3]]
#        n1 mt1
#3    Steve  32
#31 Brendan  44

#[[4]]
#       n1 mt1
#4     Dan  87
#41 Joseph  52
```

We could also `split` every row into list of dataframes and then `rbind`

```
Map(rbind, split(df1, 1:nrow(df1)), split(df2, 1:nrow(df2)))
```

whose `purrr` version would be

```
purrr::map2(split(df1, 1:nrow(df1)), split(df2, 1:nrow(df2)), rbind)
```

---

As the number of rows are same we could also use `lapply`

```
lapply(1:nrow(df1), function(x) rbind(df1[x, ], df2[x, ]))
```

Comment: Thank you!. All 3 versions work well, is there a preference which one to choose?

Comment: @mrsama Actually, all of them do more or less the same thing, so you could select any of them. I would still prefer the 1st `Map` solution as it is more clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

Do with `split`

```
df=rbind(df1,df2)
split(df,rep((seq.int(nrow(df1))),2)) # or split(df,c(seq.int(nrow(df1)),seq.int(nrow(df2))))
$`1`
      n1 mt1
1   Mike  48
11 Peter  32

$`2`
      n1 mt1
2   John  64
21 Chris  23

$`3`
        n1 mt1
3    Steve  32
31 Brendan  44

$`4`
       n1 mt1
4     Dan  87
41 Joseph  52
```

Answer (score 0):

Another intuitive way to do it would be with `for` loop

```
df1 <- data.frame(n1=c('Mike','John','Steve','Dan'),
                  mt1=c(48,64,32,87), stringsAsFactors = F)
df2 <- data.frame(n1=c('Peter','Chris','Brendan','Joseph'),
                  mt1=c(32,23,44,52), stringsAsFactors = F)
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)) {
  assign(paste0("m", i), rbind(df1[i, ], df2[i, ]))
}
```

This will create several new data frames- in this case, m1, m2, m3, and m4 -with each one having corresponding rows from both df1 and df2.

Comment: Thanks but this does not work for me. What does the m do in "paste0(m, i)?

Comment: Sorry but that should be "m".  It is just a string character to create the name of the new data frames.  For instance, it will create dataframes named m1, m2, m3 and so on.  The error is fixed.

Comment: I would like if this worked but it gives me NULL when I run it?

Comment: This is weird then because it works for me.  I have included the full code.  Try copy pasting and see if it works.  After the successful run, you should have four new dataframes in your working environment named m1, m2, m3 and m4.

Comment: I copied and pasted your edited text but I still get NULL when I run it. Do I need a special library to run your code?

Comment: Nope, this is all base R.  Not sure then what is going on.  How do you get NULL, like an error, or you just don't get anything?